# Can a contract know at what position in a callcode an argument begins?

Tags: evm, calldata, callcode

using for example inline assembly with [`calldatacopy(t, f, s)`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=calldatacopy), which copies s bytes from `calldata` at position f to memory at position t

in a call to for example `function newContract(bytes data) { ... }`

is it possible for a contract to know at what position in the `callcode` the `data` bytecode begins ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general answer is that it follows the conventions of [the ABI](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#examples). You can work it out based on those rules.

In this particular case, the encoding of `data` will start at position `36`. The first four bytes will be the message signature, and the next 32 will be a pointer to the location of `data`'s representation.

Note that the first 32 bytes of `data` will give the length parameter, so if you actually want just the raw data inside the `bytes`, that begins at `68`.

Comment: This is the answer for parsing `calldata` in a function, but is it the same if the function is invoked by `callcode`?  The question asks about `calldata` within a `callcode`... won't the `calldata` be different from the original `calldata`?  (An example could also be helpful.)

Comment: I don't believe the question is actually asking about `callcode`, it seems to be a typo for `calldata`. That said, my understanding is that it should be the same. `callcode` and `delegatecall` attempt to work as similarly to a normal message as possible.

One place where it might be different is solidity "internal" functions. To be honest, I don't fully understand how those work.